# Find an example (as small as possible) of a graph with $6$ vertices of degree $3$ and other vertices with degree $\leq 2 $ with $12$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

How can we find an example (as small as possible) of a graph with $6$ vertices of degree $3$ and other vertices with degree $\leq 2 $, with $12$ edges. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Petersen's graph.

[image][image][image]

Delete 3 successive outer edges. You will receive the second graph. It already satisfies your conditions.

But, as [benguin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121903/benguin) stated in the answers, this is not minimal according to the number of vertices.
Denote $N$ as a number of vertices with degree $\le 2$. We have

$$12 \le \frac12\left(6\cdot3 + N\cdot 2\right).$$

So, we have $N \ge 3$.
Finally, note the two outer vertices could be merged and the resulted graph will be optimal.

Comment: Then 3rd one is our required graph?

Comment: @MatheMagic, yes

Answer (score 4):

Since the graph must have $12$ edges, the sum of the degrees of the vertices must be twice that: $24$. Notice the $6$ vertices of degree $3$ contribute $18$, and thus we are still short by $24-18 = 6$. We are allowed to add vertices whose degree is at most $2$; in order to minimize the amount of vertices needed, we'll try to only add vertices whose degree is $2$. Since there are $6$ degrees left to account for, then we want $3$ vertices of degree $2$.

In order to arrange these vertices into a graph, I believe it is possible to construct a graph with the desired properties if the vertices of degree $3$ and the vertices of degree $2$ belong to two different connected components.

Answer (score 4):

Just a graph that fits your requirement and is "as small as possible". A construction and calculation approach is already given by the other answers (@Andrei Kalunchakov, @benguin).

[image: small graph]

Answer (score 4):

It turns out 9 vertices is the minimum possible.  It must be at least 9, since the number of edges (which equals 12) is half the sum of the degrees (by the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)).  (With fewer than 9 vertices we have degree sum at most $3+3+3+3+3+3+2+2=22$, allowing only 11 edges.)

Using `geng` which comes with Nauty, we can generate all the $12$-edge $9$-vertex graphs, then filter out those with degree sequence $(3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2)$.  A simple example is $K_{3,3} \cup C_3$.

It turns out there are 68 non-isomorphic examples, and they are drawn below (with the vertices marked with their degrees):

[image]